# How to integrate two Parse Tree data structures from two different NLP Tools

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface, abstract-class, stanford-nlp

I am now using both [Stanford CoreNLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml) and [Fudan NLP](https://github.com/xpqiu/fnlp/) to process Chinese natural language. These two tools both generate the Parse Tree, i.e. `Stanford CoreNLP Parse Tree` and `Fudan NLP Parse Tree` (let me call them `STree` and `FTree`).

And I need to make use of `STree` and `FTree`, and do some costumed method on them, which sharing the same function signature and various in implement details. So the best practice is to define a Class which can generate from both `STree` and `FTree`.

However, these two kind of parse tree is totally different in aspect of data structure. So I can think of two solutions:

1. Define a class `Tree` with generic type, which would be passed by content type of `STree` and `FTree`. Plus a `TreeFactory` which then pass these two kind of content types and generate relative Trees. If I follow this way, I cannot take apart the two kind of implementation of the same method.
2. Define a interface or abstract class `Tree`, which contains several methods. Then extend this interface into two different subclass corresponding to `STree` and `FTree`. If I follow this way, the `children` in subclasses will not be the subclass of `super.children`.

   ```
   class TreeNode { 
       List<TreeNode> children; 
       //... 
   };
   class STree extends TreeNode { 
       List<STree> children; // Problem: not a subclass of super.children
       //... 
   };
   class FTree extends TreeNode { 
       List<FTree> children; // Problem: not a subclass of super.children
       //... 
   };
   ```

I wonder which is the better choice. Or can anyone provide a more adaptable solution.

Following is the brief definition of `FTree`:

```
// Declaration edu.fudan.nlp.parser.dep.DependencyTree;
public class DependencyTree implements Serializable {

    // tree node content
    public String word;
    public String pos;
    // sequence number in sentence
    public int id;
    private int size=1;
    // dependancy relation type
    public String relation;

    public List<DependencyTree> leftChilds;
    public List<DependencyTree> rightChilds;
    private DependencyTree parent = null;

    // ...
};
```

Definition of `STree`:

```
// Definition edu.stanford.nlp.trees.LabeledScoredTreeNode
public class LabeledScoredTreeNode extends Tree {

    // Label of the parse tree.
    private Label label; // = null;
    // Score of <code>TreeNode</code>
    private double score = Double.NaN;

    // Daughters of the parse tree.
    private Tree[] daughterTrees; // = null;

    // ...
};
```

Comment: It looks like the Fudan tree here is a *dependency* parse tree. Do you mean to mix the Fudan dependency parse with the Stanford NLP constituency parse? If you mean to use dependency parses from CoreNLP as well, you probably want to use a [`GrammaticalStructure`](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/GrammaticalStructure.html).

Comment: @JonGauthier Yes, the `GrammaticalStructure` is exactly what I meant when referring `STree`. However, what I really need is to make use of _the Dependency Tree_ from both Fudan and Stanford tools and implement several methods, which apply the same operators with different details on the two defferent trees.

Comment: Another solution would be to create your own meta model. Let's call it MyMetaTree and then provide methods for STree and FTree to be converted into your own domain model.

Comment: @mike isn't that option #1? I agree it sounds better, though I'd be worried about hard-to-debug downstream errors resulting from mistakes / inconsistencies in the conversion.

Comment: Kind of, but he should drop the generic type. The meta model should stand for itself. And yes, I agree that's it's not an easy task to create a meta model

Comment: @mike If I drop the generic type, it is hard for me to build a meta model, for the data structure of these two are totally different from each other. I originally meant to pass different content type to the generic type.

Comment: @JonGauthier Here comes the basic problem: if I have a abstract class `Tree`, then intuitively it should have a data field of `List<Tree> children` or something like that. Then if I extend `Tree` to `STree`, the `STree.children` is inherited from `Tree.children`, which means that the `STree.children`'s elements will be `Tree` literally rather than `STree`, by no means can I apply `STree`'s unique methods on it. If `Tree` does not contain `children`, it serves like an _Interface_.

Comment: @stanleyerror A metamodel solves the problem of different datastructures, since it has its own. Don't mix it up with delegation/decorator pattern. You would need a factory with `MetaModel createFrom(STree tree)` and `MetaModel createFrom(FTree tree)`.

Comment: @mike Then I should make my own metamodel's data field compatible for both `STree` and `FTree`, rather than pass the datatype of them to generic type. And what I really need is one model rather than a hierarchy of models corresponding to `STree` and `FTree`?

Comment: @stanleyerror Yes. Designing meta models is not easy. Before you program, you should maybe make a concept with pen and paper. The meta model should be able to represent all the information from Ftree and STree (and maybe more variants), and you have to design **how**.

Answer (score 1):

I think more fundamental question is that how you are going to use the syntactic analysis result from two different parsers. As the two trees could be totally different in structure and I am not sure how you are going to use the two parsers result together or part of speech level!

Another possible option is that if you are doing annotation on each word in the sentence, you can combine output from Standford NLP tool and FudanNLP tool.

Technically it's always possible to use the option suggested by Mike to have a MetaModelNode interface with concrete implementation classes of STreeMetaModelNode and FTreeMetaModelNode.